# Finding transfer function from bode plot

Tags: control, matlab

I try to estimate a system transfer function by hand calculation from a bode plot data but I could not succeed yet and I need someone help.

it will be appreciated if anyone explains or refer me to a source where I can learn to estimate the TF with Matlab tools/codes (I couldn't do it with system identification toolbox)

frequencies (rad/s): 0.5 ;  1 ; 2 ;  3 ;  4  ;  5  ;  7.5;  10 ;  15 ;  30 ;  50

magnitudes (dB)    : 12  ;  6 ; 0 ; -3 ; -14 ; -20 ; -26 ; -30 ; -30 ; -34 ; -40

phase (degree)     :-37  ; -54; -109 ; -112 ; -103; -106; -107; -86 ; -86 ; -86  ; -86

Comment: Did you try plotting the values on a semilog plot (frequencies on the log axis)?  And look for the -3dB points and the phase angles at those points?

Comment: Yes I did and I try to estimate it as a normal minimum phase system by hand calculation but the magnitute slopes and phase are not correlated (+-20dB//+-90 deg). it seems like system has transport delay or a non-minimum phase system which has pole or zero on the right hand side. Therefore, I thought I need algorithm or a toolbox to exactly estimate it.

Comment: Is this approximated first order bode? Can you solve it by hand?